# Submit App store build of same app which actually has a less version number than its TestFlight build

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, testflight

I have an App Store approved build version 1.1 which will be expected to release soon. Mean while I am going to release a TestFlight beta build of same app in the version number 1.2. Apple won't allow developers to release beta build in the same version of the approved version otherwise I will go with 1.1 for beta build. If I released beta build and in case there is a need to cancel the approved build, Can I submit the App Store build in version 1.1 again

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will be able to submit the same version number as long as the Build number is different.  Apple just does not allow two binaries with the same build number.